# How to load custom post data into a sidebar using ajax?

Tags: ajax, wordpress, sidebar

I have a list of custom posts, and I want to have a sidebar, wherein the information associated with a post selected from the list to load.

Comment: StackOverflow is not an appropriate site for this question.

Comment: why is not appropiated ?

Comment: You're asking users to provide you with a complete solution rather than solve a specific problem you're encountering.

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on using ajax to do this then you will need an API for your WordPress site to call back into. Take a look at http://wp-api.org/. It won't necessarily be easy, but you should be able to get it setup and running and then put a piece of JavaScript in a widget to make the call and display the data.

Be careful, that plugin is under active development.

IMO, it would be easier to do this without ajax. Off the top of my head I would say that you could define a shorttag in your functions.php file and then put it in your widget. If the widget appears on a page with a post, pick up the post id, fetch the meta data, and display it.

Cheers!

=C=